# I have followed all instructions but cannot get TLS 1.3 on NGINX to show

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am trying to enable TLS 1.3 on my server. I have followed an abundance of articles on Google and have the same configs settings in my own config, yet I cannot get it past TLS 1.2.

I am on Ubuntu 16.

I am using NGINX version 1.14 which is built with OpenSSL 1.1.1.

```sh
➜ nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.14.2
built with OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018 (running with OpenSSL 1.1.1a  20 Nov 2018)
TLS SNI support enabled
```

These are all the required versions of the software I have seen that are needed to support TLS 1.3.

I'm using Chrome 72 and SSL Labs when testing the certificate but it just always says it's on 1.2.

Here is the part of my NGINX config file that's related to the SSL options

```sh
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;
ssl_ecdh_curve X25519:secp256k1:secp384r1:prime256v1;
ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES25
ssl_session_timeout  10m;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 216.146.35.35 216.146.36.36 valid=60s;
resolver_timeout 2s;
```

I got the Ciphers from https://cipherli.st.

With these configuration options, I cannot get past the TLS 1.2 protocol.

I believe this is everything I can think of that might be causing me issues, but I can tell you of anything further you might need to know to help my case.

Thanks,

Chris

Answer (score 8):

Enabling TLSv1.3 on Nginx might be looking pretty straight forward, but is not documented as it should.
Cutting to the chase now. The trick is to include the SSL settings in every server block of your config. Not doing so, will result in the fact of a disabled TLSv1.3. This makes sense in the way that the tls protocol is not "upgraded" upon the first request that hits the server:

**sudo vi ssl_config**

```
add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload';
add_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
add_header Referrer-Policy no-referrer;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers TLS13-CHACHA20-POLY1305-SHA256:TLS13-AES-256-GCM-SHA384:TLS13-AES-128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_session_tickets on;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_ecdh_curve auto;
keepalive_timeout   70;
ssl_buffer_size 1400;
ssl_dhparam ssl/dhparam.pem;
ssl_stapling on;
ssl_stapling_verify on;
resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 valid=86400;
resolver_timeout 10;
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
```

And:

```
server {
    server_name xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx; #Your current server ip address. It will redirect to the domain name.
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    include ssl_config;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name www.example.com;
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    include ssl_config;
    # Non-www redirect
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    server_name example.com;
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    root /var/www/html;
    charset UTF-8;
    include ssl_config;
location ~* \.(jpg|jpe?g|gif|png|ico|cur|gz|svgz|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|htc|css|js|otf|eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)(\?ver=[0-9.]+)?$ {
    expires max;
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin '*';
    add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    access_log off;
    }
    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;
    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
      allow all;
      root /var/www/html;
      default_type "text/plain";
    }
location / {
    index index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    #limit_conn num_conn 15;
    #limit_req zone=num_reqs;
    }
error_page  404    /404.php;
#pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on php-fpm unix socket
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files       $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index   index.php;
    fastcgi_pass    php:9000; #for docker.
    #fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php7-fpm.sock; #for non-docker.
    fastcgi_pass_request_headers on;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
    fastcgi_ignore_client_abort off;
    fastcgi_connect_timeout 60;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 180;
    fastcgi_request_buffering on;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
    fastcgi_buffers 4 256k;
    fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
    fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
location = /robots.txt {
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    }
location ~ /\. {
    deny  all;
    access_log off;
    log_not_found off;
    }
}
```

Now it will work 100%, using the strongest ciphers available.
I made a blog post a while back about [how to enable TLS 1.3 in Nginx](https://admintuts.net/server-admin/docker/custom-nginx-docker-image-geoip2-rtmp-support/#how-to-enable-tlsv1-3-in-nginx).
As added bonus, as of versions 1.18.0, 1.17.10 and above,i [maintain fresh tls1.3 enabled docker images](https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/admintuts/nginx/tags?page=1)

Answer (score 1):

Your `ssl_protocols` should be ordered as `TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3`.

Then, your `ssl_ciphers` should include the list of `TLSv1.3` ciphers first (in this order):

```
TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256
TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256
```

followed by your TLSv1.2 ciphers.  Here's what [tls13.iachieved.it](https://tls13.iachieved.it) `nginx.conf` looks like:

```
ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers         TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_8_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_CCM_SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA512:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
```

And connecting to it with Chrome 72:

[image]

And the response from the site:

```
Your User Agent is:  Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.109 Safari/537.36
Your client supports the following ciphers:  0x2a2a:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256:TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:0x000a
The negotiated cipher with this server is:  TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
```

Note that the `your client supports the following ciphers` is what your web browser supports, not the server.

Comment: Hmmm, still didn't work. I added the ciphers you mentioned above. Did you mean for me to do that? I checked the site mentioned - do I need to add those ciphers instead?

Comment: Yes, you need to add the `ssl_ciphers` listed in the `nginx.conf` block above, and put `TLSv1.3` last in your `ssl_protocols`.

Comment: Appreciating your help Joe but even with the above mention suggestions, it's still showing as TLS 1.2.

Comment: This is one of those cases where the lack of private messaging on SO hampers things, but that's okay.  My suggestion at this point would be to simplify your NGINX configuration, remove your dhparam, ecdh curves, OSCP stapling, etc. and get just the bare minimum.  There is a template for nginx.conf at https://github.com/iachievedit/tls13_nginx_cosmic if you can look at that (ignore the LUA bits).  I'm sure there is something subtle going on.

Answer (score 1):

Did you also check `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoursite` and if you are using Let's Encrypt, `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf`? Only editing `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` might not be enough.

I experienced the same problem today. For me, the reason was that I use letsencrypt's Certbot. It creates `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf`, where the `ssl-protocols` are also defined. If you don't adjust them there, changing the `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` won't help.

Be careful when editing `/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf` as it is managed by Cerbot. Check, if everything is still working using `sudo certbot renew --dry-run`.

For further reading, I recommend https://libre-software.net/tls-nginx/.

Answer (score 0):

for me it was the let's encrypt nginx conf
/etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf
had to change it there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

anyone seeing this should be sure they check/adjust the protocol and cipher list in their default server block in nginx.conf also.

Answer (score -1):

Just try to start nginx with simply ssl configuration:

```
ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers         HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
```